# Netbook doesn't see wifi network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, netbook

I have a big problem with my girlfriend's netbook (asus eeepc 1008). It doesn't see any wifi network. I'm explaining the problem:

The pc use windows 7 starter
The wifi card is activate, I update drivers. It's a Atheros AR9285 wireless network adapter.
The ethernet card is activate too, when I plug a ethernet cable, the netbook can go on the web.

When I want to show all wifi network, I see nothing. When I want to add manually a wifi network, I get: "An error is occurred" (very helpful this message ^^)

I can't ping the gateway of my personal network.

My macbook can connect it on the wifi network, so I don't think it's a gateway problem.

I don't see how resolve this problem.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If the netbook came with Windows 7, it's still under warranty.  Get Asus to replace it, since it would seem that there is a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows 7 to manage your wireless, or a third party wireless manager?

If it is Windows, right click on the wireless systray icon and select "Troubleshoot Problems"

Comment: Yes I use windows to manage wireless.
Here is the error message:

It may exist a problem with drivers for the wireless card. it's traduct to french, it's not the real message. The real message is:

Il existe peut être un problème avec le pilote pour la carte "Connexion réseau sans fil".

I try to update the driver with the new version (june 2010) but nothing has changed.

Comment: Is this a new laptop or an older one?